# Magento / Wordpress integration - wp plugins were not showing up

Tags: wordpress, magento, plugins

My question relates to this post here (Fishpig's Wordpress):
[Full Magento / Wordpress integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018827/full-magento-wordpress-integration)

I've installed this plugin and almost everything is working well. I've been trying to run wordpress plugins within the blog, but these were not showing up. No issues on the installation process.
Are there any further steps I have to take or is it generally not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally not possible is the short answer to that I'm afraid.  In full integration mode your Wordpress themes and plugins will not function as they normally do as the whole thing is running through Magento.

All in One SEO will work, support for it has been added to the Magento module. Fishpig has produced a couple of additional Magento modules which can be installed and will support additional Wordpress plugins.  Indeed, this is a way for them to monetise the work that's gone into it all, so I am hoping there will be more on the way. I've got the Next Gen plugin which works well, I can recommend that. There's also a Pinterest plugin and Advanced Custom Fields;

http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration-pinterest-rss-widget.html

http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration-advanced-custom-fields.html

http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration-nextgen-gallery.html

To have a fully functional Wordpress site you will have to set it to semi integration mode and do a matching Wordpress theme I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello @McNab, http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration-nextgen-gallery.html link is not working, do you have another link?

Comment: Lol @chirag - that was over 7 years ago I wrote that!  No, I don't I'm afraid.  I'm not even a Magento developer any more.